# Is there a way to add a style to the body of an MVC view using a layout page

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC View that uses a layout page which has all the settings to display the site menu and other things.  In this particular view, I would like to add a style to the body style it has inherited from the layout page without modifying the layout page?. Is there a way to add a style to the body of a view page that is already using a layout page? For example, on this one particular page I'd like to add the following style to what it is already using for the body:

```
background: linear-gradient(174deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(33,48,153,0.7130128662793243) 63%, rgba(49,0,255,1) 100%);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sections).

You can define a section in your `_Layout.cshtml` :

```html
<!-- _Layout.cshtml  -->
@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
```

And then, fill it in your child view :

```html
<!-- ChildView.cshtml  -->
@section Styles {
<style>
/* your stylesheet */
</style>
}
```

I hope this helps you.